Does .NET 8 really support .NET Standard 2.0 (BinaryFormatter issue)?
I have a lib compiling to .NET Standard that uses BinaryFormatter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netstandard-2.0).
I also have an app compiling and running on .NET 8 and consuming this lib. In .NET 8, the binary formatter was marked as deprecated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-8.0).
When running this app in mac OS, I get a crash stating that the binary formatter serialization and deserialization are disabled to run (which makes sense).
So, my question is:
Does it make sense to say that .NET 8 supports the APIs from .NET Standard? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0
Is there are way to detect these use cases?
I understand it would be difficult to detect this in compile time, given that I'm clearly compiling to .NET Standard (on purpose), but it would be cool to detect this before running the code and getting the crash.
Thank you,
Tiago Fernandes

Hmm, tricky one. Unless the library targets .NET 8 (or later) you're unlikely to see the warnings/errors.

@phuzi right :P since these were different projects and within different repositories, it was difficult to detect. But can we say .NET 8 implements .NET Standard in that sense?

I would suspect that it doesn't really but it's likely up for debate and therefore probably OT for [so]

If you had tests covering the code that uses BinaryFormatter in the library then the tests would fail when upgrading the test project to .NET 8.

Seems you can enable it by code AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization", true);

@Magnus Although you can, that doesn't really help detect usages of deprecated/obsolete APIs.
